# How to stop getting error messages in terminal

Tags: command-line, chromium

When I open the chrome browser through terminal, I keep getting some error messages in the terminal.

```
[3067:3067:0801/081834:ERROR:CONSOLE(121)] "Uncaught Strict get failed, invalid object.", source: https://www.google.co.in/xjs/_/js/k=xjs.ntp.en_US.aonB8i0MSEg.O/m=jsa,ntp,pcc,csi/rt=j/d=1/t=zcms/rs=AItRSTPAQ-zB-ZqIjVvZ6la9yQedBN_Uxw (121)
[3067:3067:0801/081834:ERROR:CONSOLE(121)] "Uncaught Strict get failed, invalid object.", source: https://www.google.co.in/xjs/_/js/k=xjs.ntp.en_US.aonB8i0MSEg.O/m=jsa,ntp,pcc,csi/rt=j/d=1/t=zcms/rs=AItRSTPAQ-zB-ZqIjVvZ6la9yQedBN_Uxw (121)
```

How can I get rid of these? 
I have an alias *chrome* created for chromium browser in `.bashrc` file. I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

Try `chrome 2>/dev/null`

This will route all output on STDERR to a null file

Or to get rid of all standard output and error, use this

```
chrome >/dev/null 2>&1
```